# Get token and google id in @react-oauth/google

Tags: reactjs, google-signin

I've implemented login with google functionality for my login page and I've used `@react-oauth/google` package. And in my app to dispatch the login action I need 4 things - name, email, token & googleId. 
Previously I had used `react-google-login` package and there I was getting all these items. But from current package docs I found...

```
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

<GoogleLogin
  onSuccess={credentialResponse => {
    console.log(credentialResponse);
  }}
  onError={() => {
    console.log('Login Failed');
  }}
/>;
```

From the response I'm getting name and email but there's no googleID or token which is required. Below is my dispatch function

```
  const googleSuccess = (resp) => {
    let decoded = jwt_decode(resp?.credential);
    const email = decoded?.email;
    const name = decoded?.name;
    const token = resp?.tokenId;
    const googleId = resp?.googleId;
    const result = { email, name, token, googleId };
    dispatch(googleLogin({ result, navigate, toast }));
    console.log(result);
  };
```

I had to use `jwt-decode` as the response I was getting was a JWT token. 
And this is the Button component

```
       <GoogleLogin
          onSuccess={(resp)=>googleSuccess(resp)}
          onError={() => {
            console.log("Login Failed");
          }}
        />
```

I checked other ways like

```
import { useGoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

const login = useGoogleLogin({
  onSuccess: tokenResponse => console.log(tokenResponse),
});

<MyCustomButton onClick={() => login()}>
  Sign in with Google {' '}
</MyCustomButton>;
```

but here I'm not getting name, email and googleID.

**So Any suggestions?**

Comment: Have done similar to you; need id_token to pass down to services; did you work it out?

Comment: @9swampy I had added `flow: "auth-code",` in onsuccess handler...but didn't get the expected output

Answer (score 8):

You can get id_token (JWT) by using the personalised button for authentication.

`useGoogleLogin` hook is wrapping the Authorization part in new Google SDK

```
const googleLogin = useGoogleLogin({
onSuccess: async tokenResponse => {
  console.log(tokenResponse);
  // fetching userinfo can be done on the client or the server
  const userInfo = await axios
    .get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.access_token}` },
    })
    .then(res => res.data);

  console.log(userInfo);
},
// flow: 'implicit', // implicit is the default
```

});

But my recommendation for you as you have a backend, go with **Authorization code flow**, which will return code that you will exchange with your backend to obtain because it is more secure way.

Here is the source of entire discussion with examples for `auth-code` flow for client-side and back-end as well: https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth/issues/12

Comment: How can i get the idtoken with personalised button ?

Comment: @SudipShrestha you can find that in userInfo from code above

Comment: It works for me! I was originally using the GoogleLogin component, why do they gives different return, why can't it just return the same thing like useGoogleLogin... I wonder

Comment: @Arkady I'm not getting an ID token with the response from https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo, any idea why that would be excluded? other properties like email, picture, and sub are included.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [this webpage](https://livefiredev.com/in-depth-guide-sign-in-with-google-in-a-react-js-application/) which clears out many of questions related to the topic of Google's auth flow, specifically about *standard Google button* vs *custom login button* and respectively *credential* vs *access_token* response data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered challenges in obtaining the access token directly from the Google Login button using a similar approach. However, I found success by utilizing the 'useGoogleLogin' hook provided by the '@react-oauth/google' library, which facilitated the retrieval of the access token

```
const login =  useGoogleLogin({
      onSuccess:token=>{
        console.log(token) // it will have the access token
      },
      onError:error=>{
        console.log(error)
      }
    })
  return (
        <Button startContent={<FcGoogle size={25} />} color='' onClick={login} > Sign in with Google</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this , it worked perfectly for me...

```
   const login = useGoogleLogin({
           onSuccess: async tokenResponse => {
               const token = tokenResponse.access_token;
             // fetching userinfo can be done on the client or the server
             const userInfo = await axios
               .get('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', 
                 { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${tokenResponse.access_token}` },
               })
             const result = userInfo.data;
            // contains name, email & googleId(sub)
           },
         });
```

Comment: It looks like you copied the code from the top voted answer and edited it a little bit

Comment: The website has a big problem with duplicates, both questions and answers...